# Property of a series function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove that $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\cos(z/n))$ is a entire function.

**Try:**
The idea I have is to use the Taylor series to convert $\cos(z/n)$ into a power series and cancel that 1, but I would be left with a double series and it would be a bit more complicated. Any help or hint to make it easier.

Comment: It is uniform limit of entire functions (partial sums) - this is enough. You do not have to expand each item in its own series, just estimate  $(1-cos z/n)$ in the neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Estimate, how? If it is to find the limit in a neighborhood of 0, the limit gives 0 when n tends to infinity. @Salcio

Comment: @Salcio Estimating $1-\cos (z/n)$ in a neighborhood of $0$ would be useful to prove that $f$ is analytic in $0$, not in the whole plane.

Comment: @JamesA. Show that it converges uniformly in any circle $|z|<R$. For that consider the tail $\sum_{n> R}$, the rest of the sum is a finite sum of entire functions.

Comment: I want it to converge but by Weierstrass's M criterion, but I want to know if it is true for the complexes that $|\sin z|\le |z|$?  because I have the idea that $1-cos(z/n)$ can be transformed into $2\sin^2(z/n)$ and if I had that inequality, I would already be @Gary

Comment: @JamesA. Note that for example $
\left| {\sin z} \right| \le \sinh \left| z \right| \le (\sinh 1)\left| z \right| < 2\left| z \right|
$ for $|z|\le 1$.

Comment: Any ideas to bounded in general to use the comparison criteria? @Gary

Comment: Let $R>0$ be arbitrary. Using the estimate I provided, if $|z|<R$ then $$
\left| {2\sum\limits_{n = \left\lfloor R \right\rfloor  + 1}^\infty  {\sin ^2 (z/(2n))} } \right| \le 2\left| z \right|^2 \sum\limits_{n = \left\lfloor R \right\rfloor  + 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} < 4|z|^2 <4R^2
$$ and the sum of the first $\left\lfloor R \right\rfloor$ terms is certainly entire.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks u. @Gary